# New JBoss generation and configuration on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

Eclipse
Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149

JBoss 6.1.Final

I have a workspace which have several projects, and i used to have a working server which i generate and configure with support of colleagues.

But now my server does not work and i need a new JBoss server.
If you want to know what happened to server you can look at:

[JBoss server does not get changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328547/jboss-server-does-not-get-changes)

I generated a new one but can not configure it to contain my workspace projects, and connect with my DB schemas.

In Eclipse, in Server view, i can see my projects under my new server, but when i start the server, it prints nothing about my DBs and projects. And i see error when call a project on server, through a browser.

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this tutorial:

**[Eclipse configuration for JBOSS](http://tutslink.blogspot.com/2012/04/eclipse-configuration-for-jboss.html)**